# Lightning Button Variant for "outline-brand"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to apply a specific variant to a lightning button. Lightning Design System says there is a button variation called [outline-brand](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/#Outline-Brand). It applies the `slds-button_outline-brand` class to the button.

However, the [component documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:button/example) doesn't show that variant option available. I've tried something like this:

```
<lightning:button variant="outline-brand" label="Cancel" />
```

Can this be done as a `variant` or do I need to use `class` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lightning Component Library (LCL) tends to lag behind the Salesforce Lightning Design System (SLDS) by about one release on average; two different teams are working on these two parts of Salesforce, so it is strictly true that there must be some lag time between when a style is defined and when it makes it in to the LCL. For now, assuming the style is available (I haven't checked), you should be able to use it as a class in this release, and it will likely become a variant you can use in the next release (note: there's no guarantee of this, but it seems reasonable). The class version, of course, will always work in to the foreseeable future now that SLDS has stabilized its design patterns.